# How to save data in enum type column in CakePHP

Tags: mysql, enums, cakephp-2.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CakePHP 2.0 - Use MySQL ENUM field with form helper to create Select Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600330/cakephp-2-0-use-mysql-enum-field-with-form-helper-to-create-select-input)

I have a checkbox in my form. That checkbox has an enum type column in database. If that checkbox is checked, I need to save 1 otherwise 0 in that column.

I am using CakePHP's save function to save all form values. When I checked that checkbox, the column updated with 1, but if I unchecked and then press the submit button, it's updated with an empty value.

How can I save enum type values using checkbox in CakePHP?

Comment: `ENUM( '0', '1' )` isn't exactly good database design -- `TINYINT` is much better for boolean values.

Comment: Anyway, there's no direct support for ENUM in CakePHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you change your column type to tinyint (0/1) (in MySQL for example):

```
ALTER TABLE users CHANGE COLUMN active active tinyint not null default 0;
```

Or, validate if the value is pass (or checked), for example:

```
if($this->request->data['User']['active'] == null) {
    $this->request->data['User']['active'] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enum will take Null as default value for your column, if you do not define anything. update table definition and set "0" as default. It will solve your problem.